# Limit visibility for the user to the directory

Tags: debian, ftp

How can I make such thing, to give no visibility to user except only one directory (especially within FTP)?

I should give some sample scenario:
Someone logs to my server with some username and password and that person cannot affect my file system except that directory.

There is proftpd and apache2 installed on the server. How can I do that thing, I wonder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ProFtpd you can use the [**DefaultRoot**](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_DefaultRoot.html) directive to chroot users into their home directory tree. In your proftpd.conf set

```
DefaultRoot  ~
```

to lock all users. There is more discussion in the link above and [here](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Chroot.html) too.

Answer (score 1):

You need a chroot jail.

Here is how you can achieve this if using vsftp.
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/vsftp-chroot-users-limit-to-only-their-home-directory.html

You might also want to consider using publicfile instead.